# Citrix not retaining users auto text

Tags: windows-server-2008, citrix

One of my users in the farm are losing their autotext every time they log out and in, anyone have any ideas :)

So far i have tried

http://www.nullskull.com/q/19607/not-saving-macros-and-autotext-on-citrix-profile.aspx

but it appears that citrix chooses when to actually bother to save it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a logoff script to copy the file to the users' homedrives, a subfolder under their roaming profile or an entirely different place.

Then use a logon script to copy the file the other way.

You can either add the few lines of commands to existing scripts, or use a GPO to assign the logon/logoff scripts to the Citrix servers. This would require enabling loopback processing, as logon/logoff scripts are per-user settings.